# Can this equation involving binary operations (XOR) and 32-bit integers be solved?

Tags: abstract-algebra, computational-mathematics, binary-operations

I need to solve the following equation for $x$:

$$y = (x * (z + A) + B) \oplus (x * z + C)$$

where:

- $\oplus$ is the binary XOR operator for 32-bit integers
- all variables are 32-bit integers
- all variables except for $x$ are known
- the variables $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the constants $32757935$, $-29408451$, and $-5512095$
- EDIT: $z$ isn't a constant, and varies, but is unique for every pair of $x$ and $y$.

If it helps, this problem is based on/similar to this equation:
[How to solve this equation for $x$ with XOR involved?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884500/how-to-solve-this-equation-for-x-with-xor-involved)

Comment: Do you know $z$? $2^{32}$ is small. Is brute force a valid answer?

Comment: @YBerman Yes, $z$ is known and is unique for every value of $x$ and $y$ (it isn't a constant). Bruteforcing isn't an option as I'll need to be doing multiple calculations fast.

Comment: If $z,A,B,C$ are all known, what's there to solve? Just plug everything into the equation and out comes $y$. Are you looking for a fast algorithm? A factorization?

Comment: I have an idea. @JustinSapp pick a programming language that you like. C?

Comment: @Χpẘ I'm trying to solve for $x$ (a.k.a. isolate $x$ from the rest of the equation).

Comment: @YBerman C/C++ is fine.

Comment: @JustinSapp will finish code tomorrow.

Comment: @JustinSapp You want to invert the equation? Such that you have $x(y)$ instead of $y(x)$?

Comment: @Χpẘ I have the values of $y$ and $z$ and want calculate or solve for $x$ (the variable that is not known), if it is possible. This problem (and its solution?) is related to a similar equation, linked above: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884500/how-to-solve-this-equation-for-x-with-xor-involved

Comment: Ok, I see. You want to invert the equation to get $x(y)$. I'm thinking you could treat all variables as 32 term polynomials, one term per bit. I just tried to work this out for a 2 bit number and it's complicated, so nevermind. Probably adapting the accepted answer at the link is the way to go. Except for the factor $(z+A)$ your equation is already in the same form as that at the link. You just need to substitute $G=z+A$ for $A$ at the link.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the three operations $\oplus$, $\times$, and $+$ have the property that modification of the upper bits do not change the lower bits.
That is if $\square$ is one of the three operations, $x \square y = z \mod 2^n$ will not change if you substitute $x$ with $x + 2^m$ for $m \geq n$.

So you can do a depth first search populating the lower bits first and checking the partial equality using a mask.

```
// TODO(yberman) do code
```

Note I suspect (but do not know) there is no closed form solution, as these operations don't play well together. IDEA uses a mixture of xor, multiply, and add for example. [Even just addition and xor is mathematically messy if you allow rotations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher))

Comment: Seems like that would be lot less efficient (CPU-wise) than just a straightforward calculation. If the compiler already has all the operands in registers, the calculation is around 6 x64 assembly language instructions. But a depth first search would easily take hundreds of instructions. I guess I still haven't figured out what the OP wants.

Comment: He wants a algorithm for given fixed $z$ and $y$ find $x$. Initially I think he thought there would be a closed formula $x =f(y,z)$ which would do the trick.